# Modifying measurements in a Qiskit circuit

Tags: qiskit, programming

Assume my function Qiskit receives a certain `circuit` as an input. How do I check if this circuit already has some measurements appended to it? If so, how can I modify them? For example, if there are measurements on certain qubits, I would like to remove those in order to add some more gates, and then add the measurement of all qubits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably by converting the circuit to a `DAGCircuit`, which can be done using the method `from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag`. From the DAG you can get properties, such as any measurement operations, by using the function `my_dag.named_nodes('measurement')`. `DAGNode` objects are returned which will tell you the properties of the measurement. You can then remove nodes using `my_dag.remove_op_node(a_measurement_node)`, it is preferable to remove and add nodes than to modify inplace. Following this you could convert the `DAGCircuit` back to a `QuantumCircuit` using `from qiskit.converters import dag_to_circuit` and then append any measurement operations as desired.

Comment: Wow, that's quite involved but will hopefully work :) Why can't I just copy the gates one by one to another circuit, until I reach the measurement?

Comment: That would also work, but it would mean creating a new circuit, but if you are fine with doing that it should work

Comment: Could you explain how exactly I should do it this way?

Comment: You could iterate over `QuantumCircuit.data()` which returns a list like object of `(instruction, qargs, cargs)`. You should then be able to do `new_circuit.append(instruction, qargs,cargs)`

Answer (score 1):

Since the last answer, now there is an easier solution:

Get an ordered dictionary of the operators in `circuit` and check if `'measure'` is part of it:

```
ops = circuit.count_ops() # ordered dictionary of operators and their count
if 'measure' in ops.keys(): # iterate over the keys
    # do something, e.g. remove all measurements
    circuit.remove_final_measurements()
else:
    print('no measurements found')
```

Then you can add any gates you want and measure again using `circuit.measure_all()`